# How can I directly get a printout using information in a SQL database by a button onclick in a php page?

Tags: php, sql, printing, onclick

Following is the php page(KIOSK.php) with the button 'English Courses' which runs another php file(addEnglish.php) that has a insert query statement for the database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="Text/css" href="../CSS/KIOSK.css">


<body style="background-color:Black">


<div class="btn" align="center">
    <div class="btn-group1">
    <button class="button1">Exams</button>
    <button class="button2" onclick="addEnglish.php">English Courses</button>
</div>

</br>
<div class="btn-group2">
    <button class="button3">Library</button>
    <button class="button4">Other</button>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Following is the php file(addEnglish.php) which has the insert query....to add a new record in the database.

```
<?php


$servername="localhost";
$username="BCadmin";
$password="Admin@123";
$db='the_roshan';


$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$db);

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed:" .$conn->connect_error);

}

$sql="INSERT INTO token_english (engtoken_type) VALUES ('English')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully!";
}else{
echo"Error:". $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}   

$conn->close();


?>
```

My requirement is to get a printout which has the details of the newly created record in the database when the 'English courses' button is clicked. Can I get a printout without showing any print preview and prints directly?

Comment: Just a question, but you will Insert `English` in your table everytime someone click on the button ? With no information about the user who click ?

Comment: `onClick` requires a Javascript function. Create a form that submits to `addEnglish.php`?

Comment: yes, it will insert English .....the table is automated to create id, and time stamp automatically when English is submitted. No need information about user.....@MickaëlLeger

Comment: Can you help me with the javascript @kerbholz